# Sharing GUI windows between Macs

Tags: macos, screen-sharing

I have two macs on the same local network. What I want to do is to ssh into one mac from the other and open GUI windows. I **do not** want to share the whole screen, just windows I open from the terminal.

Between Linux computers it is possible to do `ssh -X user@host`, an equivalent to this on mac is exactly what I want.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: To clarify, are the apps you want to run native Mac apps, or X11 apps? If the latter, you can do the same as you can on Linux (if you install XQuartz at both ends)... but I'm guessing you mean the former, for which there is no practical solution I'm aware of. The OS X window manager doesn't have this functionality.

Comment: Okay, thank you for answering my question. I was talking about native Mac apps.

Comment: Do you need to use terminal? For native apps, depending on your sharing preferences, you can find the computer on the network, connect to it, and then navigate to the application using finder.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you start an Application that uses X11, just like that : `ssh -X user@host`

You can run most "Linux GUI" X11 applications on mac as described here using docker: [How to run a Linux GUI application on OSX using Docker](http://kartoza.com/en/blog/how-to-run-a-linux-gui-application-on-osx-using-docker/)

Make sure to check out [XPRA for Mac](http://xpra.org/), too.
You can forward X11 apps on mac or forward the whole mac desktop using xpra, to install do

```
brew install Caskroom/cask/xpra
```

to shadow the desktop

```
/Applications/Xpra.app/Contents/Xpra_NoDock.app/Contents/MacOS/Xpra  shadow --bind-tcp=127.0.0.1:10000
```

etc.pp.